# Adding rows to a dataset when they are missing in the given group

Tags: sas

Say I have a dataset like this

```
  day product sales
1   a       1    48
2   a       2    55
3   a       3    88
4   b       2    33
5   b       3    87
6   c       1    97
7   c       2    95
```

On day "b" there were no sales for product 1, so there is no row where day = b and product = 1. Is there an easy way to add a row with day = b, product = 1 and sales = 0, and similar "missing" rows to get a dataset like this?

```
  day product sales
1   a       1    48
2   a       2    55
3   a       3    88
4   b       1     0
5   b       2    33
6   b       3    87
7   c       1    97
8   c       2    95
9   c       3     0
```

In R you can do `complete(df, day, product, fill = list(sales = 0))`. I realize you can accomplish this with a self-join in proc sql, but I'm wondering if there is a procedure for this.

Comment: FYI - our convention for questions like this is only to have the tag of the language you're using, not the one you're showing examples from.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular example you can also use the SPARSE option in PROC FREQ. It tells SAS to generate all the complete types with every value from DAY included with PRODUCT, so similar to a cross join between those elements. If you do not have the value in the table already it cannot add the value. You would need a different method in that case.

```
data have;
input n day $ product sales;
datalines;
1   a       1    48
2   a       2    55
3   a       3    88
4   b       2    33
5   b       3    87
6   c       1    97
7   c       2    95
;;;;
run;

proc freq data=have noprint;
table day*product / out=want sparse;
weight sales;
run;

proc print data=want;run;
```

Comment: Yep, this gives exactly what I wanted if I substitute `out=want(drop=percent)` for `out=want`

Answer (score 3):

There are, as usual in SAS, about a dozen ways to do this.  Here's my favorite.

```
data have;
input n day $ product sales;
datalines;
1   a       1    48
2   a       2    55
3   a       3    88
4   b       2    33
5   b       3    87
6   c       1    97
7   c       2    95
;;;;
run;

proc means data=have completetypes;
  class day product;
  types day*product;
  var sales;
  output out=want sum=;
run;
```

`completetypes` tells SAS to put out rows for every class combination, including missing ones.  You could then use `proc stdize` to get them to be 0's (if you need them to be 0).  It's possible you might be able to do this in the first place with `proc stdize`, I'm not as familiar unfortunately with that proc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `proc freq` using the `sparse` option.

Code:

```
proc freq data=have noprint;
table day*product /sparse out=freq (drop=percent);
run;
```

Output:

```
 day=a product=1 COUNT=1 
 day=a product=2 COUNT=1 
 day=a product=3 COUNT=1 
 day=b product=1 COUNT=0 
 day=b product=2 COUNT=1 
 day=b product=3 COUNT=1 
 day=c product=1 COUNT=1 
 day=c product=2 COUNT=1 
 day=c product=3 COUNT=0
```